# how to setup properly environment for testing using React, Redux and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, redux, jestjs

I have a problem while setting up the environment for testing a React app that uses Redux and Typescript

Here is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import Login from './Login'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history'

describe('Rendering', ()=>{

    const initialState = {
        user: {
            id:'',
            name: "",
            email: ''           
        },  
        loading: false,
        error:{
            message: ''
        }
    }
    const mockStore = configureStore()
    let store

    test('renders initial screen', () => {  

        const history = createMemoryHistory()
        store = mockStore(initialState)

        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <MemoryRouter history={history}>
                    <Login />
                </MemoryRouter>
            </Provider>
        )

        const loginScreenMessage = screen.getByRole('heading', { name:/login/i } );
        expect(loginScreenMessage).toBeInTheDocument();
        
    })

})
```

This is the Login component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from 'store/hooks';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import {loginUserAction} from 'store/actions/AuthAction'
import ValidationErrors from 'components/ValidationErrors'

function Login() {
    
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const loading =  useAppSelector(state =>state.auth.loading)   
    const [form , setForm] = useState({
        email : "",
        password : ""        
    })

    const error = useAppSelector(state =>state.auth.error)    
    
    useEffect(()=>{     
        dispatch(ErrorAction({message:''})                  
    }, [])

    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setForm({
            ...form,
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        })
    }   
    
    const submitLogin = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()      
        try{
            await dispatch(loginUserAction(form))
            navigate('/home')
        }catch{
            //
        }
                
    }                       

    return (        
        <div className="login" data-test="component-login">                     
            <div className="w-full mx-auto sm:w-8/12 md:w-6/12 lg:w-4/12 bg-white pt-5 px-10">
            <AiOutlineTwitter className="text-5xl text-twitter" />             
            <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold my-10 ">Login</h1>
            { error.message &&                                             
                <ValidationErrors errors={error} />                    
            }   
            <form onSubmit={submitLogin}>                  
                <div className="special-label-holder relative mt-5">
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        id="email"
                        name="email"
                        placeholder=" "                         
                        className="input-form" 
                        value={form.email}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <label 
                        className="text-lg h-full left-2 text-gray-500 top-3 overflow-hidden pointer-events-none absolute transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out" 
                        htmlFor="email"
                    >
                        Email, phone or username
                    </label>
                </div>                      
                <div className="special-label-holder relative mt-5">    
                    <input 
                        id="password"
                        type="password" 
                        name="password"
                        placeholder=" "                                                     
                        className="input-form" 
                        value={form.password}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <label 
                        className="text-lg h-full left-2 text-gray-500 top-3 overflow-hidden pointer-events-none absolute transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out" 
                        htmlFor="password"
                    >
                        Password
                    </label>
                </div>               
                <button disabled={loading} type="submit" className="button flex items-center justify-center w-full mt-5 disabled:opacity-50">
                    <div className={`loading animate-spin mr-1 ${!loading ? 'hidden' : '' } `} /></div>
                    Login
                </button>                              
                </form>   
            </div>              
        </div>      
    );
}

export default Login;
```

store/hooks.ts

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store';

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

store/store.ts

```
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import reducer from './reducers'

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;
```

store/reducers/index.ts

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import {authReducer} from './authReducer'
import {errorReducer} from './errorReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
    error: errorReducer
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export default rootReducer;
```

store/reducers/authReducer.ts

```
import { Auth } from "interfaces/Auth";
import {Action, ActionType} from 'store/types'

const initialState: Auth = {
    user: {
        id:'',
        name: "",
        email: ''   
    },  
    loading: false,
    error:{
        message: ''     
    }
};

export const authReducer = (state = initialState, action: Action) : Auth => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionType.LOGIN_USER_START:
        case ActionType.CHECK_USER_START:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            };
        case ActionType.SET_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,             
                user: action.payload,
            };
        case ActionType.SET_USER_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,             
                error: action.payload,
            };  
        case ActionType.PURGE_AUTH:
            return state;
            
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And this is the error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'loading' of undefined
>
> ```
>   13 |     const navigate = useNavigate()
> > 14 |     const loading =  useAppSelector(state =>state.auth.loading)
> ```

What is happening? thanks.

**Edit**

Now I modified this store/reducers/authReducer.ts

```
export const initialState: Auth = {
```

...
Now I am exporting it, to get it in my test:

```
...
import {initialState} from 'store/reducers/authReducer'

describe('Rendering', ()=>{

    ////I added auth
    const initialStateLogin = {
        auth: initialState           
    }
...
```

Now my test is passing, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `initialState` in your test has no nested `auth` state that your component seems to be expecting. Adapt the initialState in your test to reflect what the app uses. Better yet, use the same initialState your app is using.

Comment: Thanks man, now my test is passing, see my updated answer, although I am not sure if this is the best way to setup the test environment, I have seen other configurations, but I was not able to make it works properly, only this. Thanks.

Comment: @felipe You could consider using the `connect()` API instead of the useSelector and useDispatch hooks. However this is not the officially recommended way anymore (according to redux toolkit). Testing a plain (unconnected) component is much easier than always mocking the redux infrastructure in tests. Anyway, I'd give the redux-toolkit docs a good read, maybe they offer more guidance on testing.